# pywinauto print control identifiers does not show required controll buttons

Tags: python, automation, windows-installer, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate installation (install anyware type) using pywinauto.
When I use function to dispaly controlls  "print control identifiers()", I see only buttons like "minimize", "close" , "maximize" and window name. There is no "next button" and other required buttons, that I need for automating this installation.

this is how it looks after using this function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0GTY.png)

this is how installer window looks :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgQfD.png)

code sample:

```
w_handle2 = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'PTC Solution Installer', class_name='SunAwtFrame')[0]
window2 = app.window(handle=w_handle2)
window2.print_control_identifiers()
```

Could you pleas help me, with my issue? Is ther any other way to check the controlls? I was also trying to use other software like inspector.exe, it tells me the windows name , but nothing about controlls.

If there is no other way, then maybe there is possibility to use function for clinking mouse, with some additional precision. For example finding specific string on installer window and clicking on it, or getting button string location and passing it, to mouse click coordinates.

Topic Update image with

inspect tool screenshot:

[screenshot with inspect tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYaJH.png)

winspy screenshots:

[winspy screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geQwr.png)

[winspy screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm7bP.png)

[winspy screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVKCb.png)

Comment: could you post the image of inspect.exe, will take a look how it looks like

Comment: Many installers have silent option like `-s` or `/s` to operate without GUI. Usually you can get help by running the installer in cmd.exe with option `/?`.

Comment: Also there is no info how `app` object created. Which backend was used?

Comment: Hello, backend that was used is - "uia".

Comment: Hello I have also added screenshots with winspy and inspect tool,  could you please check and let me know how I can get access to buttons ?